# command line composer command not defined

Tags: composer-php, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am following the composer developer Tutorial: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html

Everything worked till the point when I am running from the command line:

```
$ composer archive create -a dist/my-network.bna --sourceType dir --sourceName .
-bash: fds: command not found
```

The composer command was not found. When built by `npm install` the script can execute the composer command within the package.json

Next I installed php composer from:  https://getcomposer.org - Which might be the wrong package?

```
$ composer network deploy


  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  Command "network" is not defined.
```

My 2 questions: is this the right package, if not how can I remove it safely?
Furthermore, how can I execute the composer command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `npm install -g composer-cli` -- please refer to the documentation.

Comment: I followed the documentation:
`npm install -g composer-cli`
`npm install -g generator-hyperledger-composer`
`npm install -g composer-rest-server`
`....`
but got the error anyway

Comment: Try `npm uninstall -g composer` it sounds like you've installed the "wrong" composer npm module.